# Ajuda com o google maps api

Tags: javascript, maps

olá pessoal como posso fazer pra carregar a minha div com o google maps após clicar em um botao, e nao deixar que o maps carregue junto com o carregamento da pagina? obrigado!

Comment: Podes colocar o código do Google maps que tens?